# Count the number of times a number appears in a sorted array - searching algorithm

Tags: python, binary-search

I would like to ask why this part `if j == len(nums) or nums[j] != target: return 0` can be executed when it returns -1, but not when it returns 0? And is there any other problem with the whole code block?

Here's the full code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def search(self, nums, target):
# find the right bound
        i, j = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while i <= j:
            m = (i + j) // 2
            if nums[m] < target:
                i = m + 1
            elif nums[m] > target:
                j = m - 1
            else:
                i = m + 1 
        right = i
        if j == len(nums) or nums[j] != target:
            return 0

# find the left bound
        i, j = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while i <= j:
            m = (i + j) // 2
            if nums[m] < target:
                i = m + 1
            elif nums[m] > target:
                j = m - 1
            else:
                j = m - 1 
        left = j
        if i == len(nums) or nums[i] != target:
            return 0
        return right - left - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not account for the case where the `nums` list is empty. In such a case, `j` will be `-1` (`len(nums)-1`).

Thus, an `IndexError` occurs in `nums[j] != target` as `-1` is not a valid index for an empty list.

Additionally, the condition `j == len(nums)` or `i == len(nums)` will never be true as `i` and `j` are bounded by 0 and `len(nums)-1` (their initial values).

Therefore, your code should be

```
class Solution(object):
    def search(self, nums, target):
# account for empty lists
        if len(nums) == 0:
            return 0
# find the right bound
        i, j = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while i <= j:
            m = (i + j) // 2
            if nums[m] < target:
                i = m + 1
            elif nums[m] > target:
                j = m - 1
            else:
                i = m + 1 
        right = i
        if nums[j] != target:
            return 0

# find the left bound
        i, j = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while i <= j:
            m = (i + j) // 2
            if nums[m] < target:
                i = m + 1
            elif nums[m] > target:
                j = m - 1
            else:
                j = m - 1 
        left = j
        if nums[i] != target:
            return 0
        return right - left - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given code, the line `if j == len(nums) or nums[j] != target: return 0` is used to check if the target element is not present in the nums list. If it is not present, it returns `0`. This means that the target value is not found in the list, and therefore, there are no occurrences of the target value.

Regarding your question about why the code can execute when it returns `-1` but not when it returns `0`, it's important to note that the code block you mentioned is not responsible for returning `-1`. The code you provided only returns 0 when the target element is not found in the list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. Yes, I understand that, but I still don't know why it doesn't work when it comes to 'return 0', the error message shows: list index out of range